# $P(A_i) = \frac{1}{n} = \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} $

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, factorial

could somebody kindly help me understand the intuition why $P(A_i) = \frac{1}{n}  = \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} $. according to the text:

"To find the probability of the union, we’ll use inclusion-exclusion. First,

$$P(A_i) = \frac{1}{n} = \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} $$

for all $i$. One way to see this is with the naive definition of probability, using the
full sample space: there are $n!$ possible orderings of the deck, all equally likely, and
$(n−1)!$ of these are favorable to $A_i$ (fix the card numbered $i$ to be in the $i$th position in the deck, and then the remaining $n − 1$ cards can be in any order). Another way to see this is by symmetry: the card numbered $i$ is equally likely to be in any of the $n$ positions in the deck, so it has probability $1/n$ of being in the $i$th spot."

i can understand the intuition behind $1/n$, however, i can't get $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$ and why is $(n-1)!$ of these are favorable to $A_i$

fyi, this is the first part solution of the de Montmort’s matching problem,
"Consider a well-shuffled deck of $n$ cards, labeled 1 through n. You flip over the cards one by one, saying the numbers 1 through $n$ as you do so. You win the game if, at some point, the number you say aloud is the same as the number on the card being flipped over (for example, if the 7th card in the deck has the label 7). What is the probability of winning?"

kindly advise. Regards

@Siong Thye Goh & @ N. F. Taussig. thank you for the clarifications. Here's an update from what i understand from your examples, kindly verify whether it illustrates (n-1)! in this context. 
For simplicity, i'm using $n$ = 3, with i,j,k and having i as the $i$ card. Therefore, there are a total of 6 permutations for n!. where the 6 permutations are: 

('i', 'j', 'k')
('i', 'k', 'j')
('j', 'i', 'k')
('k', 'i', 'j')
('j', 'k', 'i')
('k', 'j', 'i')

therefore, with (n-1)!; whether $i$  is at the first, second or third positions, there are 2 permutations from any of the 3 positions.

first position: 
('i', 'j', 'k')
('i', 'k', 'j')

second position: 
('j', 'i', 'k')
('k', 'i', 'j')

third position: 
('j', 'k', 'i')
('k', 'j', 'i')

by fixing $i$ card to one of the three positions, gives me $\frac {(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac {2!}{3!} = \frac {2}{6} = \frac {1}{3} = \frac {1}{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the probability, $\Pr(A_i)$, that the $i$th card is in the $i$th position.

There are $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ cards in the deck.  For the favorable case, there is one way to place the $i$th card in the $i$th position.  There are $(n - 1)!$ ways to arrange the remaining $n - 1$ cards in the remaining $n - 1$ positions.  Hence,
$$\Pr(A_i) = \frac{1 \cdot (n - 1)!}{n!} = \frac{(n - 1)!}{n!} = \frac{(n - 1)!}{n(n - 1)!} = \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: thank you for the answer, could you elaborate on "There are (n−1)! ways to arrange the remaining n−1 cards in the remaining n−1 positions." with text or permutations example(s) instead of algebra arrangements?

Comment: It is just an application of the Multiplication Principle.  There are $n - 1$ ways to fill the first open position, $n - 2$ ways to fill the second open position, $n - 3$ ways to fill the third open position, and so forth.  There are $(n - 1) - (k - 1) = n - k$ ways to fill the $k$th open position since $k - 1$ of the $n - 1$ open positions have already been filled.  Hence, there are $\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1} (n - k) = \prod_{j = 1}^{n - 1} j = (n - 1)!$ (let $j = n - k$) ways to fill the remaining $n - 1$ open positions with $n - 1$ different cards.

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig, thank you for the remainder about the multiplication principle, i went back and redraw a simple permutation tree and had a better picture of what (n-1)! represents. I've updated my question with new information, kindly see whether the intuition is in the right direction.

Comment: Your example does correctly represent the problem when $n = 3$, although I would have used the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and taken the favorable cases to be those with a $1$ in the first position.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the $i$-card matches the $i$-th position, we win the game. It doesn't matter how the other cards are arrange.

For example consider $n=4$, and $i=2$.

$1234$

$1243$

$3214$

$3241$

$4213$

$4231$

are all favorable. We just need $2$ to be at the right position and we are free to permute the other cards.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, could you give more concrete example(s) relating to the rational behind (n−1)? The example that you have provided pivots towards 1/n. And aren't all permutations of $n$ favorable since all of them contain 2 where;  $ P(n,n) = n(n-1)... 1 = n! $

Comment: All permutation of $n \ge 2$ but they might not be at the right position, for example, $4132$ is not valid as the $2$ is not at the right position. There are a total of $n!$ permutations. Out of those only $(n-1)!$ of them are having $2$ at the right location. We count $(n-1)!$ by fixing the $2$ and allow the rest to permute.

Comment: thank you for your replies,  i've updated my question with new information you've provided. kindly verify whether the intuition correct.

Comment: I believe you want $i$ to be at the correct location? then you want $i$ to be the second position for the second position case.

Comment: thank you, corrected the typo. with that corrected, i assume I've gotten the intuition right for (n-1)!?